# Авторизация на двух сайтах

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, авторизация

Есть два сайта. Оба на asp.net. Сайты используют одну бд и по смыслу взаимосвязаны. Хотелось бы чтобы пользователь, будучи авторизованным на одном сайте, мог бы открыть второй сайт и тоже оказывался авторизован и на втором сайте (таблица пользователей в бд как и вся бд для них общая). Возник вопрос, как это сделать? То есть как дать понять второму сайту, что этот же пользователь уже авторизован на первом, и значит должен быть залогинен и тут? Ведь читать куки с другого сайта насколько я понимаю нельзя и небезопасно.

Comment: я однажды уже задавал этот вопрос но ни кто не смог ответить , и потом на многих сайтах этот вопрос задавал , ответов получил Ноль

Comment: можно воспользоваться технологией SSO для asp.net, в ней есть возможность передавать куки между доменами

Answer (score 1):

как вариант можно использовать SSO

[Identity Server 3 Standalone Implementation Part 1](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-Standalone-Implementation-Part-1)

А если проще то при авторизации пользователя писать куки для обоих сайтов, на два домена.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.